# Is that worth to learn LINQ for hobbyists?

Tags: linq

Is that worth to learn LINQ for hobbyists or the professionals (who are free from formal job requirement)? We can achieve the same thing that LINQ does via traditional language functionality such as loop, array, etc.

Why bother to duplicate the way to achieve the same objective?

Comment: [dreamincode.net: How important is LINQ to an aspiring .NET developer?](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/217486-how-important-is-linq-to-an-aspiring-net-developer/)

Comment: Vote to close, better as a blog entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found using LINQ to be very beneficial, from the standpoint that I don't have to write the for loop to iterate over a collection and perform some operation. Rather, I can use a single line LINQ statement to do that for me.

One simple example could be `someCollection.OrderBy(c => c.propertyOne);` Doing that on your own would take a bit more code.

Answer (score 5):

I find LINQ tends to let you focus more on intent. In other words, *what is the code doing* rather than *how is the code doing it*. Or to put it yet another way, it's more of a [declarative form of programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) (like functional programming) rather than [imperative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) style.

Comment: +1, noted. But over depending to LINQ will make our skills not transferable to other languages. Lest, sooner or later our proficiency of that traditional skills will become rusty due to LINQ?

Comment: Using LINQ may not be directly transferable, but it does make you think of solutions differently (which is always a good thing). But why not take advantage of language features available in whatever language you are using. Why limit yourself to techniques common to all programming languages. Do that and you'll be stuck using if statements and loops and never anything else. As an aside, LINQ also offers the advantage that if you can use almost identical code for various data sources (object collections, database tables, xml files).

Answer (score 3):

LINQ isn't so much something you *need* to learn, it's just something that you probably just *will* learn. It's now just part of the framework along with some cool additional syntax. If you aim to write clean, maintainable code then you will no doubt want to write code which leverages LINQ extensions.

Apart from the syntactic sugar of "from ... select ... where" in C#, you'll find that LINQ is leveraging other bits of the framework/languages anyway - that is, extension methods, enumerators, lambda expressions, and delegates. All of these are increasingly hard to avoid anyway.

When it comes to using frameworks that provide their own LINQ proimplementations, for example, Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL, then that's another story. I would learn those based on requirements. In your case, if your side-project needs some DB CRUD stuff then you might look at either of those.